# Are there project-specific svgPaths for QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, configuration, path

I have a QGIS project that needs custom SVG symbols. These are all in a directory next to the `myproject.qgs` project file (and FWIW, everything is under version control):

```
myproject/
  .git/
  myproject.qgs
  symbology/
    icon1.svg
    icon2.svg
```

QGIS only finds the symbols `icon1.svg`, `icon2.svg` when I add the `/absolute/path/to/myproject/symbology` directory to the global `SVG paths` settings in QGIS.

However, this means that everyone else who checks out this repository will have to adjust their global QGIS configuration before they get correct map renderings.

Is there a more elegant way to do that? For example, is it possible to define custom `SVG paths` entries directly in the project file?

Comment: It is possible (qgis-ltr 3.4) to choose the symbol inside the Layer Styling Window by file selection. If you do that, the marker path is relative and stored inside the project file.

Comment: see here with pictured instructions: https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/android-data-structure.html